# NodeJS & Multer: stop uploading file if error occurs

Tags: javascript, node.js, file-upload, upload, multer

hello i creating file upload with Node & Multer, it works but problem is that if error occur (like user did not fill other fields) it still uploads file which i don't want

i literally don't know what to do because i am doing it first time so wish if anyone got experience with this. here is my code

```
const storage = multer.diskStorage({

  destination: (req, file, callback) => {
    const userPath = path.join(imgStoragePath, req.userId);
    fs.mkdir(
      userPath,
      () => callback(null, userPath)
    )
  },

  filename: (req, file, callback) => {
    const filenameParts = file.originalname.split('.');
    const ext = filenameParts.pop();
    const basename = filenameParts.join('.');
    const additionalPath = Date.now() + '' + uuid() + '' +             
Math.floor(Math.random() * (2000 - 500)) + 500;
    callback(null, basename + '-' + additionalPath + '.' + ext);
  }

})

const upload = multer({
  storage,
  limits: '1mb'
})


   router.post('/', upload.single('image'), async (req, res) => {
  //code
})
```

if error occurs it should return error message and send it to server and stop code execution and don't do anything, it does it but also uploads file, i know this will happen because `upload` is middleware and middleware executes first and i want it to prevent it. Thanks!

Comment: What errors are you trying to handle here? For example, if the form in the front end contains a file upload and an input field and the user submitted the form by only uploaded the file without filling in the input, should the code return an error response in that case? or are your trying to handle error with file upload itself such as file size crossing the max limit or file type other than the specified ones?

Comment: i meant first case, when user filled file input and did not fill other input (but if you have clue to second case i'll be glad to hear it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okay so multer is not really responsible for validating your form inputs, it's sole purpose is to allow you to upload a file to the backend. Now getting to the issue you're trying to solve

- you could have html validation in the front end to make sure the user fills in all the `required` fields before submitting the form
- you could make a backend check to make sure that all the required fields have been filled in

In order to use the 2nd step you can use a function like this

```
 export const setRequired = (...args: any): boolean => {
   let isValid = true;
   _.forEach(args, value => {
     if (isUndefined(value)) isValid = false;
   });
   return isValid;
 };
```

```js
 const isValid: any = setRequired(file, first_name, last_name);
```

The function uses typescript and lodash and checks that all the parameters specified exist. So before you perform any operation in your backend, pass in the required fields to the function which will return a boolean to notify you if all the required fields have been received from the front end.

About the 2nd part related to file size and file type errors for multer, you can try something like this

```js
 const storage = multer.diskStorage({
 destination(req, file, cb) {
   cb(null, path.join(__dirname, `path_to_folder`));
 },
 filename(req, file, cb) {
   const ext = path.extname(file.originalname).toLowerCase();
   const file_name = uuidv4() + "_" + ext;
   cb(null, file_name);
 },
});

const upload = multer({
 storage,
 limits: { fileSize: 2000000 }, // In bytes: 2000000 bytes = 2 MB
 fileFilter(req, file, cb) {
   const ext = path.extname(file.originalname).toLowerCase();
   if (ext !== ".png" && ext !== ".jpg" && ext !== ".jpeg") {
     cb(new Error("Error: Unacceptable file format"), false);
   } else {
     cb(null, true);
   }
 },
}).any();
```

```js
  router.post("/", (req, res) => {
    upload(req, res, async err => {
      if (err) {
        console.error(err);
        // An unknown error occurred when uploading.
        // the err object will contain the reason for the multer error
      } 

      if (req.files && req.files[0]) {
        // file has been saved 
         console.log(req.files[0].filename);
      }

    });
  },
);
```

Comment: const setRequired is responsible for only file or every input?

Comment: @ilia1 it is responsible for the checking if a value exists or not, you can pass it whatever you want, if you pass it the inputs as well as the saved file it will check if those exist, if not it will return a `false`.

Answer (score 0):

```
 app.post('/upload',[
  multer({
    dest    : './uploads/',
    onError : function(err, next) {
      console.log('error', err);
      next(err);
    }
  }),
  function(req, res) {
    res.status(204).end();
  }
]);
```

//check out for this link from multer docs https://github.com/expressjs/multer#error-handling

Comment: This errorHander is called if only any error occurs inside of multer, so you could write a middleware after the multer middleware

Comment: yes but if you read my question i mentioned that i wanted error handler for multer when for example form is not filled properly